# How to crop raster in R without losing the colors?

Tags: raster, r, clip, color

I have a 2x3 raster in R, with values 1 to 6.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=3,ncols=2,xmn=0,xmx=2,ymn=0,ymx=3,vals=1:6)
colors <- c('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple')
plot(r,col=colors)
```

[image: R raster]

Now if I clip the raster, leaving the first two values out (red and orange), the color palette becomes useless.

```
r1 <- crop(r,extent(c(0.5,1.5,0.5,1.5)))
plot(r1,col=colors)
```

[image: R clipped raster]

Notice how the `extent` includes only the colors yellow, green, blue and purple from the first picture. However, these are not the colors in the second picture. The numbers in the raster are correct.

```
> values(r)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> values(r1)
[1] 3 4 5 6
```

How can I use the same color variable (`colors`) in both cases in a consistent way?

My real world problem is cropping a world raster into country maps, using the same vegetation color code.

Comment: In the first plot you have an implicit range (`zlim`) of `c(1, 6)`, so you can get the same result with `plot(crop(r,extent(c(0.5,1.5,0.5,1.5))), col = colors, zlim = c(1,6))`. Whether that will work with other palette choices is unclear though, you can control more specifically with the `breaks` argument.

Comment: You neeid to look at *categorical* rasters for mapping when your are representing discrete categories of data rather than possibly continuous numeric values. See `help(raster::ratify)`

Comment: @Spacedman My raster is categorical, with 23 levels. It's the GLC2000 (Global Land Cover) project.

Comment: @mdsumner Thank you, `zlim` apparently solved my problem.

Comment: The raster you construct in the example has integers in it but R doesn't know it represents categorical data. The raster package supports properly categorical rasters with colour palette information.

Comment: @Spacedman How do I tell the difference? My real world raster has color palette information, but I'm using a different palette with the `col` parameter on the `plot` function.

Comment: as I said, read the help for `ratify` which includes a tiny example of a landcover factor raster (but doesn't go on to colour it, but that's not too much of a leap and is probably well-documented elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Building from what @Spacedman said in comments, try ratifying the raster (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840178/how-to-write-a-raster-with-rat-factors-in-r-raster-package) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258960/access-to-attribute-in-rasterlayer-in-r)) and then using levelplot ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247894/how-to-correct-link-a-set-of-colors-to-a-rasterlayer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652580/change-raster-panel-titles-using-levelplot))

```
# make your raster
r <- raster(nrows=3,ncols=2,xmn=0,xmx=2,ymn=0,ymx=3,vals=1:6)

# ratify it, set a new colours attribute and put back into the raster
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$cols <- c('red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple')
levels(r) <- rat

# levelplot
levelplot(r,col.regions=levels(r)[[1]]$cols)
```

[image]

```
# now crop the ratified raster
r1 <- crop(r,extent(c(0.5,1.5,0.5,1.5)))

# looking at the raster will reveal and value range of 3 to 6 but an 
# attribute table including all original values & associated colours

# plot
levelplot(r1,col.regions=levels(r1)[[1]]$cols)
```

[image]

fiddling around with levelplot options etc will give you the correct legend